# Bootstrap+HighCharts.js Responsive Image Position in Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, donut-chart

I need to insert an image inside of a donut chart but when using bootstrap and when it becomes responsive the location of the image gets out of the donut chart. I want the image to be in the center of the donut chart, how can i do this?

Example Code : http://paste.ubuntu.com/16889111/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, Provide Code

Comment: You need to show code in order for people to help you.

Comment: Code is : http://paste.ubuntu.com/16889111/

Comment: You could use percentage values as with the custom circle you added. Another option is to update attr of x and y in [redraw event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) of a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for `chart.renderer.image` is using fixed values, not relative:

```
// Render the image
chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 220, 200, 60, 60)
.add();
```

I would suggest making your four values (x position of top corner, y position of top corner, image width, and image height) variables that are based on the chart container's current size.

Consider setting values based on `$('#chart').height()` and `$('#chart').width()` and test out the `chart.redraw()` and `chart.reflow()` functions to make sure the image within your chart gets updated when the viewport changes.

Here's some links in the API documentation that may be helpful to you:

- renderer.image(): http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image
- chart.redraw(): http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.redraw
- chart.reflow(): http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow